# ReactNative FlatList detect scroll to the last Item on List

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, infinite-scroll, react-native-flatlist

How can I detect if a user has scrolled to the end of the FlatList list so i can add a footer message that "You're now at the end of the list".

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use header/footer component in Flatlist
For example,

```
<FlatList
    .....
   ListFooterComponent={<Text>You're now at the end of the list</Text>}
/>
```